# Jquery toggle through random div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery and am trying to code this for a class. I want to program a button that shows a random div paragraph that will disappear and be replaced by another when you click the button again.I am using three buttons to show things. Each button has four divs with the same class name and each has one paragraph in it.  I tried using this code but it will show one paragraph and then add another under it. Another issue I'm having is that the button doesn't always work when I click it.The fourth button is for the user to input something that will be appended to each paragraph.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#first").click(function(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
   $(".firstin").eq(random).toggle();
    }); 

  $("#second").click(function() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
   $(".secondin").eq(random).toggle();
    }); 

    $("#third").click(function(){
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
   $(".thirdin").eq(random).toggle();
    });     
$("#button2").click(function(){
    var place= $("#in").val();
        if (place.length > 0){
    $("div").append("<p> text" +place+ "</p>");
    $("#in").val('');
    }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class ="firstin">
    <p>
    text
    <br>
    text
    </p>
</div>
</div><div class ="secondin">
    <p>
    text
    <br>
    text
    </p>
</div><div class ="thirdin">
    <p>
    text
    <br>
    text
    </p>
</div>
<button id = "first">Category1</button>
<button id = "second">category2</button>

<button id = "third">category3</button>

<input type = "text" id = "in" placeholder = "Text">
<button id = "button2">Text</button>
```

CSS

```
.first{ display:none;

}
</style>
```

Comment: Please include complete code so that people can help. On the post mentioned 4 buttons, but I don't see 4 buttons on your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
$("div").append("<p> text" +place+ "</p>");
```

`append()` adds whatever you have passed to it at the end of the element.
Use

```
$("div").html("<p> text" +place+ "</p>");
```

`html()` replaces the content inside